# Paragraph link outside div after make it float to the right

Tags: html, css

I want to make the "more information" element to appear inside the `div`. Am I missing something?

http://jsfiddle.net/MMKdz/

HTML

```
<div class="aside-visitus">
     <h2> H2 </h2>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</p>
    <p class="aside-caption"> <a href="#"> More information </a> 
    </p>
</div>
<div class="aside-visitus">
     <h2> H2 </h2>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    <p class="aside-caption"> <a href="#"> More information </a> 
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.aside-visitus {
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:20px 0;
}
.aside-visitus a {
    color:#4682b4;
    float:right;
}
```

The clear and display methods don't work at all.

Comment: Please include your code in the question, not just a link to a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `overflow:hidden` to the parent element. This will establish [a new block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting), thus forcing the element to contain the floated elements.

The reason this is required is because the parent element doesn't have a defined height and the child element is being floated. According to the nature of floating elements, they are essentially removed from the flow of the document; you need to reestablish the block formatting context.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/MMKdz/1/)

```
.aside-visitus {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 20px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a clearfix which does the same thing. This method has more support.

Comment: Hey mate, thank you. It's working now. I never thought that overflow would solve this problem. I thought overflow is only working for when the image is too big for a div.

Answer (score 1):

The most appropriate is use text-align: right propiety

http://jsfiddle.net/FelipeMartinin/MMKdz/3/

```
    .aside-visitus a {
        color:#4682b4;
        text-align: right;
        display: block;
     }
```

Or you can give a display: table for the div.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use float. I'd add `text-align:right` to the `.aside-caption` class.

```
.aside-caption
{
    text-align:right;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MMKdz/2/

Comment: Ah this is the easiest way yet I couldn't think for that. Thanks for this mate.

Comment: @JonP I voted your's up too. Not sure why someone downvoted both of them.

Comment: I'm still newbie and i dont understand what do you mean :/

Comment: @Anthosiastic my comment wasn't aimed at you. JoshC up voted my question by clicking on the up arrow to the left. Someone else down voted it. I thinks my answer is a reasonable one so I would have liked the person who down voted the answer to give an explanation. JoshC had the samething happen to him.